# C# set system time get extra 2 hours?

Tags: c#, time, set, system

i use somthing like this, to change system date and time:

```
public struct SystemTime
        {
            public ushort Year;
            public ushort Month;
            public ushort DayOfWeek;
            public ushort Day;
            public ushort Hour;
            public ushort Minute;
            public ushort Second;
            public ushort Millisecond;
        };
        SystemTime updatedTime = new SystemTime();
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetSystemTime", SetLastError = true)]
        public extern static bool Win32SetSystemTime(ref SystemTime sysTime);

                updatedTime.Year = (ushort)ushort.Parse(string);
                updatedTime.Month = (ushort)ushort.Parse(string);
                updatedTime.Day = (ushort)ushort.Parse(string);
                updatedTime.Hour = (ushort)ushort.Parse(string);
                updatedTime.Minute = (ushort)ushort.Parse(string);
                updatedTime.Second = (ushort)ushort.Parse(string);
                Win32SetSystemTime(ref updatedTime);
```

**But when the date has changed I get 2 extra hours in system time. Why?**

Comment: What time zone are you in? I'm not familiar with Win32SetSystemTime but maybe it is in UTC or a different time zone?

Comment: What is your time zone?

Comment: I just looked it up, SystemTime() returns the UTC time, not local time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get & Set system time in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3138974/get-set-system-time-in-c-sharp)

Comment: I'm in UTC+1 timezone

Comment: is string variable in (ushort)ushort.Parse(string); ? If so where does it come from?

Comment: You also have to account for DST which gives you the extra hour.